# Visibility in popup menus

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, popupmenu, eclipse-sirius

I have created an eclipse plugin project. I want this plugin to be available as a popup. Therefore I have created an extension point with "org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus" (I know it is deprecated now, ours is an old project.)

I want this popup option to appear only at the file level with certain extension (say xml). Currently, it is appearing anywhere on right click.

I have looked around the internet and got to know that I can add a "visibility" tag that can set rules where this popup should be visible. However, I do not know the syntax for that.

Can someone please help me out? How to set the visibility of the popup menu so that it is visible only when I right click ON the filename with extension xml?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?eclipse version="3.2"?>
    <plugin>
       <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
          <objectContribution
                adaptable="true"
                objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"
                nameFilter="*.*"
                id="org.eclipse.lyo.tools.codegenerator.ui.popupMenus.contribution.IFile">
             <menu id="org.eclipse.acceleo.module.menu" label="Acceleo Model Code Generator" path="additionsAcceleo">
                   <groupMarker name="acceleo"/> 
             </menu>
             <action
                   class="org.eclipse.lyo.tools.codegenerator.ui.popupMenus.AcceleoGenerateCodegeneratorAction"
                   enablesFor="+"
                   id="org.eclipse.lyo.tools.codegenerator.ui.popupMenus.AcceleoGenerateCodegeneratorAction"
                   icon="icons/default.gif"
                   label="Generate Java Code from Model"
                   menubarPath="org.eclipse.acceleo.module.menu/acceleo"/>
                   <visibility>
                              //what should come here?

                   </visibility>
          </objectContribution>
       </extension>
    </plugin>
```

(http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_popupMenus.html)

Regards,
Yash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`visibility` can only be a child of `objectContribution` **not** action.

In any case you can use the `namefilter` attribute to restrict the file name matching. You would only use `visiblity` to do more complex checks.

For example this is one of the JDT items:

```xml
 <objectContribution
        adaptable="true"
        objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"
        nameFilter="*.xml"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javadocexport.JavadocWizard">
     <visibility>
        <objectState name="contentTypeId" value="org.eclipse.ant.core.antBuildFile"/>
     </visibility>
```

In this

```xml
adaptable="true"
objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"
```

restricts the actions to a workspace file

```xml
nameFilter="*.xml"
```

restricts the actions to files ending in .xml

```xml
     <visibility>
        <objectState name="contentTypeId" value="org.eclipse.ant.core.antBuildFile"/>
     </visibility>
```

further restricts the actions to files with a 'content type' of 'Ant build file'

To match multiple name patterns remove the `nameFilter` and use a `visibility` like:

```xml
<visibility>
  <or>
        <objectState name="name" value="*.xml"/>
        <objectState name="name" value="*.java"/>
  </or>
</visibility>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer greg. Additional question. If I want to set more than one value for nameFilter. what's the way to do that?

nameFilter="*.xml, *.java" does not work.
addding two nameFilter also does not work.

Comment: nameFilter accepts exactly one pattern. This is XML, you can't specify the nameFilter attribute twice. Instead remove the `nameFilter` and use the visibility - see updated answer.